# problem with Double.TryParse when I do not know the culture

Tags: c#, internationalization, double

so I am using a code like this:

```
Double.TryParse(Value, NumberStyles.Any,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result);
```

and for now the language is on French but some clients may use other languages too, so I am not gonna hard code "fr-FR" in the program...but now if I pass "2,00" which should be number two, it is converting it to number two hundred.

any help on how can I do this correctly?
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the current culture for the system using [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx).  Use this instead of `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a web application, you can look for the `Accept-Language` header in the request as a hint for which locale to use for the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) property.